# Infeasible Solution, Definitely Feasible - CPLEX

Tags: cplex, opl

Basically, I have two employees, who could each be allocated to one of two roster patterns, which in turns allocates a set of shifts for each employee.

Allocate an employee a roster pattern -> that employee can only work shifts stated on that roster pattern, and must work all of them.

To that end, I have a constraint which basically states that the sum of all shifts each employee does should equal the input `shiftsPerRP`. So if a roster pattern, e.g. 0, is selected for say employee Allan, then Allan should work exactly 45 shifts.

However this constraint keeps failing and causing an infeasible solution. I can't work out what I'm missing here. Any help is appreciated.

Relevant DAT:

```
days={
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
}

People = {
    Allan,
    Joe,
};

rosterPatterns = {
    0,1
};


shiftsPerRP = {
    <0,45>
    <1,5>
};

Skills= {
    A, 
    B, 
    C
};
```

Relevant Code:

```
dvar boolean Assign[days][Hours][People][Skills];   // Indicates a shift assignment

range Hours = 0..23; 

forall(h in Hours, d in days, p in People, rp in rosterPatterns, shiftsInRP in shiftsPerRP : shiftsInRP.ID == rp)
      sum(s in Skills)
            Assign[d][h][p][s] == shiftsInRP.shifts;
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example that reproduces the issue? Also, you can try more yourself: in the IDE you can look at the conflict (check "compute conflicts" in the settings file). Also, you can export the model to LP and then in that LP file whether the constraints look as expected. Maybe there is a constraints that has empty left-hand side but a non-zero right-hand side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to analyze this, label your constraints (see the added 'c1'):

```
forall(h in Hours,
       d in days,
       p in People,
       rp in rosterPatterns,
       shiftsInRP in shiftsPerRP
       : shiftsInRP.ID == rp)
c1:
      sum(s in Skills)
            Assign[d][h][p][s] == shiftsInRP.shifts;
```

With that OPL should compute a minimal conflict that shows which constraints are infeasible. Doing that (on the command line) I found that the very first constraint generated is infeasible. The constraint has only three variables on its left-hand side but the right-hand side is 5. This can never be satisfied.

Given that you have only three elements in your set `Skills`, the left-hand side of the constraint will always have 3 variables. Thus it can take values in {0, 1, 2, 3}. If for any tuple `shifts` has a value greater than 3 then this constraint can obviously not be satisfied.

**EDIT**: It looks like you may have mixed up what should go into the `forall` and what should go into the `sum`. In order to formulate that correctly I think you will need an auxiliary variable

```
dvar boolean RosterAssigned[People][rosterPatterns];
```

that is 1 if a person is assigned to a roster pattern and 0 otherwise.
With that you can formulate the constraint as

```
forall(p in People)
  sum(h in Hours, s in Skills, d in days)
     Assign[d][h][p][s]
     == sum(rp in rosterPatterns, shiftsInRP in shiftsPerRP : shitsInRP.ID == rp) (RosterAssigned[p][rp] * shiftsInRP.shifts);
```

The left-hand side gives the number of shifts a person `p` actually works. The right-hand side gives the number of shifts required by the roster pattern. Of course you also have to add constraints that guarantee that each employee is assigned to exactly one roster pattern.

Comment: Hi Daniel! Thank you so much for your support.

I already have what you called RosterAssigned, as RosterAllocations, I dealt with that in a separate constraint which works as follows:

`forall(p in People, rp in rosterPatterns, rpD in rosterPatternDetails : rpD.rp == rp){ 
  sum(s in Skills)
   Assign[rpD.day][rpD.hour][p][s] == RosterPatternAllocations[p][rp];
    }`
In order to try your solution, I commented the above out. I also had to modify your solution as it didn't contain d for days, and the final part of the first sum refers to "rp" which only exists in the 2nd part of the sum

Comment: (sorry char limit) and it turned into this, but is still infeasible. I will now look into the debugging tips you've provided (again thank you so much!)

`forall(p in People)
  sum(h in Hours, s in Skills, shiftsInRP in shiftsPerRP, d in days)
     Assign[d][h][p][s]
     == sum(rp in rosterPatterns, shiftsInRP in shiftsPerRP : shiftsInRP.ID == rp) (RosterPatternAllocations[p][rp] * shiftsInRP.shifts);`

Comment: You have to drop `shiftsInRP in shifsPerRP` from the sum on the left side. If the sum on the left side also sums over the roster patterns then each variable will appear multple times. That can trigger infeasibility as well. Sorry about the wrt to `d` in my formulation. I updated that.